# SQL statement error with end

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Hi I keep getting a syntax error "near end" with this SQL statement any ideas whats causing it?

```
SELECT * 
FROM operations 
WHERE start = '10:00:00' 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM operations 
WHERE start <= '06:30:00' 
  AND end >= '06:30:00'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try adding backticks on the "end" word... I don't recall if it is a reserved word... use like this `\`end\` = '....'`

Comment: You don't need to use UNION if its same table. Try using `"SELECT * FROM operations WHERE start = '10:00:00' OR ( start <= '06:30:00' AND end>= '06:30:00')"`

Comment: Is it about [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax.html) or [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-syntax.html)? They are different RDBMSes that implement (and extend) SQL in different ways.

Comment: I think "end" is a reserved keyword thats whats was causing the problem thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape the keyword using backtick in MySQL or double quotes in PostgreSQL.

Also, you don't need a union here. You can use `OR`

#### Postgresql:

```
select *
from operations
where start = '10:00:00'
    or (
        start <= '06:30:00'
        and "end" >= '06:30:00'
        )
```

or

#### MySQL:

```
select *
from operations
where start = '10:00:00'
    or (
        start <= '06:30:00'
        and `end` >= '06:30:00'
        )
```